# Python File Check and Creation

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system

I am trying to check or create a directory and I am getting this error:

> /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/user/Development/americas.py Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "/home/dquezada/Development/americas.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       os.mkdir(path) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/dquezada/Development/data/maps/americas/'

Process finished with exit code 1

Below is my code:

```
path = '/home/user/Development/data/maps/americas/'

# Check if path exists, if it does not it creates it
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.mkdir(path)

wm.render_to_file(path + timeStamp + '_americas.svg')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `os.path.isdir(path)` is what you are looking for.
This will return `True` if it is a directory, or False if it isn't.
`os.path.exists(path)` is not intended for what you are using it for.

```
path = '/home/user/Development/data/maps/americas/'

# Check if path exists, if it does not it creates it
if not os.path.isdir(path):
    os.mkdir(path)

wm.render_to_file(path + timeStamp + '_americas.svg')
```

That should work for you.